# CSS grid with auto-fill and auto size

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to use CSS grid with **grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, auto)**, cells are being set to maximum width, causing one item per row.

Is it possible to have the grid cell width automatically set by the items width? I have tried inline-grid/grid-auto-flow : column, but the items do not wrap with these properties.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, auto);
  color: #444;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 250px;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1 a">A</div>
  <div class="box1 b">B</div>
  <div class="box2 c">C</div>
  <div class="box2 d">D</div>
  <div class="box1 e">E</div>
  <div class="box2 f">F</div>
  <div class="box1 g">G</div>
  <div class="box2 h">H</div>
  <div class="box1 i">I</div>
  <div class="box2 j">J</div>
  <div class="box2 k">K</div>
  <div class="box2 l">L</div>
  <div class="box1 m">M</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply move the width of the elements inside `grid-template-columns`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 250px);
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
  <div class="box g">G</div>
  <div class="box h">H</div>
  <div class="box i">I</div>
  <div class="box j">J</div>
  <div class="box k">K</div>
  <div class="box l">L</div>
  <div class="box m">M</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the original snippet so the items have varying width (I should have specified this originally), I think I need auto (or min/max content possibly) to set the cell width correctly for each item? Thank you for answering.

Comment: @FreePoint14 then it's no more a grid what you want, use flexbox instead